# Securely copy file from one Salt minion to another

Tags: copy, saltstack

How do I use Salt to securely copy a sensitive file (a cryptographic key) from one specific minion to another specific minion?  I don't want any other minion to be able to read the file.

#### Salt Mine?

The [Salt Mine](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/mine/) seems to be a logical place to start, but the documentation says:

> The Salt Mine is used to collect arbitrary data from Minions and store it on the Master. This data is then made available to all Minions via the [`salt.modules.mine`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mine.html#module-salt.modules.mine) module.

I don't want the data to be made available to all minions, just one.  In addition I don't need the periodic refresh—I only need the file to be read whenever I run `state.highstate` for the destination minion.

#### `cp.push`?

Salt's [`cp.push`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cp.html#salt.modules.cp.push) function seems like a good way to get the file to the master, except:

- it uses the `salt.transport.Channel.send()` method which is [not guaranteed to be confidential](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/topics/transports/index.html#req-channel)
- the master gives the files pushed by `cp.push` global read permissions in the master's file system
- once the file is on the master, it's not obvious how to get it to the destination minion

#### Custom External Pillar?

I could write a [custom external pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/external_pillars.html) that somehow reads the file from the source minion (how?) and then makes the file's contents available via a pillar to a second minion.  That seems like a lot of effort for a behavior that should be built-in.

Comment: Did you ever determine a solution to this problem?  I'm trying to solve this same problem right now, and I can't find a solution.  I've seen your name pop up in different places asking this question, so I hope you were able to get a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a half-answer, but maybe it'll help.

You wrote:

> once the file is on the master, it's not obvious how to get it to the
>   destination minion

and:

> I could write a custom external pillar that somehow ... makes the 
>   file's contents available via a pillar to a second minion.

That capability (the [file_tree](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/pillar/all/salt.pillar.file_tree.html) external pillar) is now in salt as of 2015.5.0.  See this [FAQ](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-deploy-a-file-to-a-specific-minion-without-other-minions-having-access-to-it).

As for how to get the file from the source minion to the master, the salt paradigm is more for the master to be the source of data.  Can you:

- Have whatever rotates the key write it to the master?
- Trigger an event that a reactor goes and fetches it via scp?
- Set up a shared NFS mount between the two minions that want to share the key (or the source minion and master)?
- Set up an https webserver on the source minion with ACLs that
  allow only access to either the master or the dest minion?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The difficulty in sharing the file uploaded by `cp.push` via a pillar is robustly knowing where the file is.  As far as I can tell, there's no clearly documented API for determining the name of the directory on the master where `cp.push` stores its files.

Comment: I can certainly use a non-Salt method to securely transfer the file, but I wanted to do this all entirely within Salt.  Salt already has a bidirectional communication channel and keys for each side, so the basic infrastructure is in place...